# Jquery open popup on button click for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When i click below button

```
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>
```

I open below popup(modal)

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I refer below example,

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

**My question:**

How can i open #myModal on button click by using javascript/jquery ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Give an ID to uniquely identify the button, lets say `myBtn`

```
// when DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function () {

     // Attach Button click event listener 
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){

         // show Modal
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AUyTH/)

Comment: I want to ask one more. I have            <input type="text" name="xx" /> in modal. I want to set value in js code    function myModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        var s = document.getElementsByName("xx");
        s.value = "adsadasdasdas";
    }; but it does not work why ?

Comment: getElementsByName returs an Array - you have to access the elment using the index like this - var s = document.getElementsByName("xx")[0];

Comment: if you have skype please add me "sonersevinc92" i always ask question on stakckverlofw.com thanks

Answer (score 2):

Below mentioned link gives the clear explanation with example.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Open-Show-jQuery-UI-Dialog-Modal-Popup-on-Button-Click.aspx

Code from the same link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "jQuery Dialog",
            width: 300,
            height: 150
        });
        $("#btnShow").click(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show Popup" />
<div id="dialog" style="display: none" align = "center">
    This is a jQuery Dialog.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is on the example link you provided:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

i.e.

`Call a modal with id myModal with a single line of JavaScript:`

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```