# Bootstrap Popup in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open popup using bootstrap in mvc on click of ActionLink. Here is my code-

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Bootstrap", null, new { @class = ".mymodal" })

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="modal fade mymodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          //Next lines of code
   </div>
</div>
</div>
}
```

but popup is not going to open. Well its opening on click of button given below-

```
<a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".mymodal"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>View</a>
```

Comment: have you tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017306/jquery-open-popup-on-button-click-for-bootstrap

Comment: I think You are not getting my point. I want open that pop up on click of ActionLink NOT ON button click

Answer (score 1):

You need to add those data attributes to your `ActionLink` `HtmlAttributes`, as follow.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Bootstrap", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success", data-toggle="modal", data-target=".mymodal", id = "yourButtonID"  })
```

You can also define a click event for your ActionLink in JQuery, and call a JQuery method to open Modal, as follow: Please note that you need to give your `ActionLink` a `id` in the `HtmlAttributes`, as specified:

```
$(function () {
    $(document)
        .on("click", "#yourButtonID", function () {
            showModal();
    });

    function showModal() {
        //set options here if needed.
        $("#YourModalID").modal('show');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Give ID to your modal and run trigger like

```
$("#modal").modal("show");
```

Answer (score 0):

Update you anchor tag with this one

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Bootstrap", null, new { @class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".mymodal" })
```