# Add click event on a jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, greasemonkey, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to create a settings button on a site which will open a jquery dialog and I want to add a click event to the button on that dialog?

How would one do this with a greasemonkey script?

I have looked at this script: [How do I pop up a custom form/dialog in a Greasemonkey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668111/how-do-i-pop-up-a-custom-form-dialog-in-a-greasemonkey-script) 
But that shows the dialog directly when opening the site. I want a button that opens the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for jQuery Popup to open on Button click ? If so, then following link will be useful for you.

[Jquery open popup on button click for bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017306/jquery-open-popup-on-button-click-for-bootstrap)

Comment: yes, but I want to run javascript code on save button in that popup, which is easy, but can't figure it out in greasemonkey

Comment: I think that can also be done by adding small jQuery code snippet in your GreaseMonkey Script. For example, if your popup's button class name is "save-button" then you can call your javaScript code on its click as given below -

Comment: $(document).on('click','.save-button',function() {
     alert("JQueryTest");
});

Comment: Thanks that is working. It was only `$('#dialogButton0').click(function(){alert('JQueryTest');});` that didn't work